# How does pagination works in elastic search?

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I am currently using elastic search python client for search the index of my elastic search.

Let's say I have 20 million documents, and I am using the pagination with `from and size` parameters. I have read in the documentation that there is a limit of `10k`. But I didn't understand what that limit mean.

For example,

1. Did that limit mean I can only use pagination (i.e. from and size) calls 10000 times?
   like `from=0, size =10`, `from=10, size =10` etc., 10000 times.
2. Or Do they mean I can make unlimited pagination calls using the from and size params but there is a size limit of 10k per each pagination call?

Can someone clarify this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pagination limit of `10k` means

- For the applied `query` only the first 10k results can be displayed.
- `from:0 size:10,001` will given an error "Result window is too large"
- `from:10000, size:10` will given an error "Result window is too large"
- In the above 2 cases we are trying to access 10000+ offset of the document of the current query, hence the exception

---

- `from` doesn't represent `pageNumber`, instead it represents `starting offset`

Answer (score 2):

The limit is called [max_result_window](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-modules.html#index-max-result-window) and default value is 10k. Mathematically this is the max value `size+from` can take.

from:1, size:10000 will give error.

from:5, size:9996 will give error.

from:9999, size:2 will give error.

[Search after](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/paginate-search-results.html#search-after) is the recommended alternative if you want deeper results.

Answer (score 0):

You can update existing index settings with this query:

```
PUT myexistingindex/_settings
{
  "settings": {
    "max_result_window": 20000000
  }
}
```

If your are creating dynamic index, you can give max result window parameter in settings.

In Java like this:

```
private void createIndex(String indexName) throws IOException {
    Settings settings = Settings.builder()
            .put("number_of_shards", 1)
            .put("number_of_replicas", 0)
            .put("index.translog.durability", "async")
            .put("index.translog.sync_interval", "5s")
            .put("max_result_window", "20000000").build();
    
    CreateIndexRequest createIndexRequest = new CreateIndexRequest(indexName).settings(settings);
    restHighLevelClient.indices().create(createIndexRequest, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
}
```

After these configurations, you can give "from" parameters up to 20 million.

But this way is not recommended.

You can review this document: [Scroll Api](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.17/paginate-search-results.html#scroll-search-results)